# Simulink: Connecting blocks within subsystems during mask initialization

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a basic question. I have a virtual subsystem with a mask defined. I want to find out how I can connect two blocks within that subsystem through the Mask Initialization Command Line.

Advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide enough details, all you need is to add/delete lines in mask initialization using appropriate logic.

You can accomplish this using following simulink APIs :

- [`add_line`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/simulink/slref/add_line.html)
- [`delete_line`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/simulink/slref/delete_line.html)
- [`gcbh`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/simulink/slref/gcbh.html)

Refer the example sections too